# Debian install: No Ethernet Card detected

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I am installing Debian 11 using a USB stick. I have a HP Pavilion, with a AMD: Ryzen 7 and the Integrated Redyon Graphics. When the installer informs me that it can't detect a Ethernet Card it gives me a list of drivers I can use. I don't know what to do in this step. I am using the iso on the Debian website, here https://www.debian.org/download.

Sorry for my lack of knowledge this is the first time doing this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130356/discussion-on-question-by-avs-debian-install-no-ethernet-card-detected).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your card may need nonfree firmware, but first you should switch to a tty ctrl+alt+f1,f2,f3,f4 until you see a shell prompt that you can type in, and try and `modprobe` followed by the suggested drivers, this will attempt to load the drivers if they exist on the system. If the `modprobe` command gives an error then try the nonfree firmware iso from https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/

Comment: Hi, is there a faster way to check all the drivers Debian gives? Possibly using the information given by the manufacturer?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that, but the non-free firmware ISO should have whatever driver you're looking for. May I ask what WiFi/Ethernet card you are using?